# How to get the objective value of provided MIP start?

Tags: python, gurobi

One can easily provide a MIP start solution, e.g.

```py
from gurobipy import Model

mdl = Model()

x = mdl.addVar(vtype="I")
y = mdl.addVar(ub = 5, vtype="I")

x.start = 2.0
y.start = 1.0

mdl.setObjective(x*x-y*y)
mdl.addConstr(x <= 2.0*y)

mdl.optimize()
```

In this example it is easily seen that the MIP start has objective value 3. How can I get the MIP start objective value by Gurobi without calculating it on my own? The `mdl.objVal` attribute is only available after calling the `mdl.optimize()` method and returns the optimal objective value then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to solve the model anyway, you could use a callback like this:

```py
from gurobipy import Model, GRB

# ... your model

# The callback saves the objective value of the first found incumbent,
# i.e. the mip start in your case
def callback(model, where):
    if where == GRB.Callback.MIPSOL:
        if model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPSOL_SOLCNT) == 0:
            # creates new model attribute '_startobjval'
            model._startobjval = model.cbGet(GRB.Callback.MIPSOL_OBJ)


mdl.optimize(callback)

print(f"MIP Start objVal: {mdl._startobjval}, optimal objVal: {mdl.objVal}")
```